# trying to get random file but getting System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException instead

Tags: c#, image, exception, directory, directoryinfo

I'm new to programming so please don't be mean to me...
I'm trying to get a random file from random folder but System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException keeps showing up.

I used codes from these answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533731/10297934

https://stackoverflow.com/a/742690/10297934

This is my code.

```
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs;
DirectoryInfo root;
root = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\items\");
subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
Random random = new Random();
int directory = random.Next(subDirs.Length);
DirectoryInfo randomDirectory = subDirs[directory];

var files = Directory.GetFiles(randomDirectory.ToString(), "*.jpg");
//this is where i get exception
var pictureToDisplay = files[random.Next(files.Length)];

pbxDateV.Image = Image.FromFile(pictureToDisplay);
```

And this is the exception i get

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\erica\source\repos\1\1\bin\Debug\forge'.'

"forge" is indeed one of name of folder from "items". The exception message showed me other random folder name each time it shows up so the code is working in some way but I'm not sure why bin folder is selected as a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

randomDirectory.ToString() doesn't return full path, it rather returns the Folder Name alone. So the  Directory.GetFiles checks in the current working directory, which is the execution Directory of the application.

You should use  DirectoryInfo.FullName instead.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(randomDirectory.FullName, "*.jpg");
//this is where i get exception
var pictureToDisplay = files[random.Next(files.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is at below line -

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(randomDirectory.ToString(), "*.jpg");
```

Because subDirs  only stores the name of subdirectories not the full path, when above line get executes it tries to find that folder in your current code working directory. So either you use randomDirectory.FullName or append root with randomdirectory as below -

```
     var files = Directory.GetFiles(randomDirectory.ToString(), "*.jpg");
```

Comment: You showed the same code line twice. You forgot to actually make the correction you described.